# Can I hide the 'Click to Add' column in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

When viewing a Microsoft Access table in Datasheet View, the right-most column is titled 'Click to Add,' allowing someone to add a new column without using the Design View. Is it possible to hide this column?

Comment: Look at Options, the cure is available there.

Comment: I didn't see the option. Where exactly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like so:

[image: Set options to avoid design changes]

Do not forget that you must close and open the database for the change to work.

Answer (score 5):

You could also right-click any column header in the table, select 'Unhide Fields' and then uncheck 'Click to Add' at the bottom of the list.

Comment: This is a clever idea how to hide *Click to Add* on table level instead of database level.